# How to display a single series total in stackLabels

Tags: highcharts

Based on: [How to position datalabel at the base of bar series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572090/how-to-position-datalabel-at-the-base-of-bar-series)

I've made some updates so that a column chart shows a stacked column for 100%-total

[image: Stacked Column]

However, using:

```
stackLabels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return this.total + '%';
        },
        enabled: true,
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        align: 'left',
        y:10
    },
```

I am getting the total 100% for the **entire** stack.  How can I adjust the formatter to only show the value for a single series?

Comment: Just updated previous answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572090/how-to-position-datalabel-at-the-base-of-bar-series) to be more clear on that this trick only works with a single series.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
formatter: function() {
    return this.total + '%';
},
```

I have trying SUM for 3 number of stack bar and it only using `enable : true;`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but to get value for individual series you can use this.y or this.x.

try

return this.x OR

return this.y